# Android Custom View: MATCH_PARENT with OnDaw don't work

Tags: java, android, layout, layoutparams

I'm new to Android but i have a simple problem.
I have a vertical linear layout, if i place here a normal button, and give it the MATCH_PARENT flag for the width and the height, the button will fill all the space. All ok.

Now i have a my simple custom view (a class that extends View) and i overrided the OnDraw method for draw a cross in the middle of the view. For draw the cross i need to get the width and the height of the control, if in the UI Layout editor of eclipse i set a fixed width and height, it works correcly (i see a preview of the cross directly in Eclipse) but if i extend the View to the borders i got only WARP_CONTENT (With button i get MATCH_PARENT), no problem, i change it in the XML, but LayoutParams width and height will return 0!! (I see the error directly in the preview of eclipse!) Why?

I tried to set manualy the width and the height in the OnWindowFocusChanged method to wait but it give me always 0.

The problem is that the view actualy have the rights dimensions but when i call the getLayoutParams().width it give me 0, so i see a white rectangle in the right position (white background of the view), but the cross is drawed on the upper-left corner!

Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you.
Mauro.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to set this parameter for your view.

```
android:layout_alignTop
```

or something related to this.i guess